# Compare values in 2 dataframes with IF conditions output (1, 0, -1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

EDIT Solution at the bottom

So I'm trying to compare two dataframes. When there is a positive crossover it should output 1, if no crossover 0, if negative crossover -1. The IF values should be outputted in a new dataframe.

I see online about iloc and lambda but not sure how to do it across 2 different dataframes?

Below shows correctly the crossover logic for positive and gives True. I would like to add the logic with 1, 0 and -1

```
macd_crossover = (macd > macd_signal) & (macd.shift(1) < macd_signal.shift(1))
```

macd example

```
              btc 
2021-08-26.   150 
2021-08-27.   200  
2021-08-28.   220
2021-08-29.   120
```

macd_signal example

```
              btc 
2021-08-26.   160 
2021-08-27.   160  
2021-08-28.   200
2021-08-29.   190
```

expected output

```
              btc 
2021-08-26.   0 
2021-08-27.   1 (crossover happens)
2021-08-28.   0
2021-08-29.   -1 (crossover happens)
```

SOLUTION (for me)

```
df_macd_diff = df_macd - df_macd_signal 
df_macd_crossover = pd.DataFrame(np.select(condlist= [(df_macd_diff > 0) & (df_macd_diff.shift(1) < 0), (df_macd_diff < 0) & (df_macd_diff.shift(1) > 0)], choicelist = [1, -1], default = 0), index = df.index, columns = df.columns)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data along with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to merge 2 dataframes into one merged dataframe with `pd.merge`. After that just apply your logic in that merged dataframe.

Comment: hmm ok feels a bit cumbersome since they have same labels (ticker name) was hoping for an easy dataframe comparison. So you suggest pd.merge and then loop over with iloc or something?

Answer (score 2):

So here is what data I used :

```
macd_example = pd.DataFrame({"dt": [pd.to_datetime("2021/08/26"),pd.to_datetime("2021/08/27"), pd.to_datetime("2021/08/28"), pd.to_datetime("2021/08/29"), pd.to_datetime("2021/08/30")], "btc": [150, 190, 220, 220, 290]})
macd_signal = pd.DataFrame({"dt": [pd.to_datetime("2021/08/26"),pd.to_datetime("2021/08/27"), pd.to_datetime("2021/08/28"),pd.to_datetime("2021/08/29"),pd.to_datetime("2021/08/30")], "btc": [140, 200, 240, 230, 200]})
```

Resulting on these dataframes :

```
macd_examle
          dt  btc
0 2021-08-26  150
1 2021-08-27  190
2 2021-08-28  220
3 2021-08-29  220
4 2021-08-30  290
macd_signal
          dt  btc
0 2021-08-26  140
1 2021-08-27  200
2 2021-08-28  240
3 2021-08-29  230
4 2021-08-30  200
```

First, merge the two dataframes on the dates :

```
merged_df = macd_example.merge(macd_signal, on='dt')
```

Giving us :

```
    dt  btc_x   btc_y
0   2021-08-26  150 140
1   2021-08-27  190 200
2   2021-08-28  220 240
3   2021-08-29  220 230
4   2021-08-30  290 200
```

Then, we use the difference between the two values, and a shift :

```
merged_df["results"] = merged_df["btc_x"] - merged_df["btc_y"]
merged_df["results_shifted"] = merged_df["results"].shift(periods=1)
```

Resulting in :

```
    dt  btc_x   btc_y   results results_shifted
0   2021-08-26  150 140 10  NaN
1   2021-08-27  190 200 -10 10.0
2   2021-08-28  220 240 -20 -10.0
3   2021-08-29  220 230 -10 -20.0
4   2021-08-30  290 200 90  -10.0
```

Now, with a bit of logic, you can use *numpy.select* :

```
conditions = [(merged_df["results"] > 0) & (merged_df["results_shifted"] <= 0), (merged_df["results"] < 0) & (merged_df["results_shifted"] >= 0)]
values = [-1, 1]
merged_df["crossover"] = np.select(conditions, values, default=0)
```

And you obtain :

```
    dt  btc_x   btc_y   results results_shifted crossover
0   2021-08-26  150 140 10  NaN 0
1   2021-08-27  190 200 -10 10.0    1
2   2021-08-28  220 240 -20 -10.0   0
3   2021-08-29  220 230 -10 -20.0   0
4   2021-08-30  290 200 90  -10.0   -1
```

Please note that this is only one way of doing it, I am pretty sure there are better ways to do it.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I got like 20+ tickers. But your method made me think, this can be simplified I would say. 

1) macd - macd_signal -> will give us a new df with difference in values 
2) the crossover is when it goes negative or positive, so could compare the value with value.shift(1) on the df itself

Could this be done in np.select or would it np.where or sth?

Comment: For more than 1 ticker you can use groupby apply and shift only on the group

Comment: Adding to my above comment sth like 

df_macd_diff = df_macd - df_macd_signal 

df_macd_crossover = df_macd_diff.where((df > 0) & (df.shift(1)) < 0, 1).where((df < 0) & (df.shift(1)) > 0, -1)

Comment: Using your np.select I can:

df_macd_crossover = np.select(condlist= [(df > 0) & (df.shift(1) < 0), (df < 0) & (df.shift(1) > 0)], choicelist = [1, -1], default = 0)

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration and help added solution in the description :)